# Atalho para parar tomcat no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Alguém sabe um atalho para parar o tomcat no Eclipse?

Já andei pesquisando e não achei nada de útil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão o atalho é  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: Não deu certo aqui não

Comment: O foco tem que estar na aba Servers para funcionar, infelizmente.

Comment: Entendido. Obrigado.